# can't remove 'wget.control': Input/output error

Tags: linux, openwrt

I tried to install wget with a new version on openwrt, but it failed, then I'm unable to remove or reinstall wget again.

```
opkg install /mnt/sda1/wget_1.16.3-1_ramips_24kec.ipk
```

I got the result:

```
Upgrading wget on root from 1.16.2-1 to 1.16.3-1...
Collected errors:
 * pkg_get_installed_files: Failed to open //usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.list: No such file or directory.
 * pkg_get_installed_files: Failed to open //usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.list: No such file or directory.
 * pkg_get_installed_files: Failed to open //usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.list: No such file or directory.
 * pkg_get_installed_files: Failed to open //usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.list: No such file or directory.
 * wfopen: //usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.control: Input/output error.
 * wfopen: //usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.postinst: Input/output error.
 * wfopen: //usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.postinst-pkg: Input/output error.
 * wfopen: //usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.postrm: Input/output error.
 * wfopen: //usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.prerm: Input/output error.
 * wfopen: /usr/bin/wget-ssl: Input/output error.
 * pkg_write_filelist: Failed to open //usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.list: Input/output error.
 * opkg_install_pkg: Failed to extract data files for wget. Package debris may remain!
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package wget.
 * opkg_conf_write_status_files: Can't open status file //usr/lib/opkg/status: Input/output error.
```

I tried to remove /usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.control manually

```
rm /usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.control
```

but I got the same answer

```
rm: can't remove '/usr/lib/opkg/info/wget.control': Input/output error
```

Though I cannot remove these files, I can still read their contents.
How to deal with the problem?